Are there free ternary ring of operators?
I am interested in separable ternary rings of operators. For separable $C^*$-algebras we have the maximal group C*-algebra of the free group on countably many generators that quotients onto every other separable $C^*$-algebra. Is there a separable TRO with an analogous property for separable TROs?

What is the notion for quotient maps or morphisms in general for TROs?

@DavidGao, it is a linear map that respects the TRO product. As I mentioned freeness, we can further restrict this to contractive linear maps that respect the TRO product.
http://agt2.cie.uma.es/~loos/jordan/archive/univenvtro/univenvtro.pdf

Such an object can be constructed via a universal construction, similar to the construction of various kinds of "universal" $C^\ast$-algebras. For a "concrete" way of constructing such a TRO, consider the class of all separable TROs $T$ with countably many contractions $\{x_n\}_n$ generating $T$ as a TRO. Let the index set $I$ enumerate all isomorphism classes of such objects (i.e., $(T_1, \{x^{(1)}_n\}_n)$ and $(T_2, \{x^{(2)}_n\}_n)$ are isomorphic if there is a TRO isomorphism $T_1 \simeq T_2$ that sends $x^{(1)}_n$ to $x^{(2)}_n$ for all $n$). For each $i \in I$, choose a representative $(T_i, \{x^{(i)}_n\}_n$). Let $T = \prod_{i \in I} T_i$ and $A$ be the sub-TRO of $T$ generated by $\{(x^{(i)}_n)_i\}_n$.
There is also an "abstract" way of constructing this $A$. For this consider the free algebraic object $F$ with countably many generators equipped with a triple product $[\cdot, \cdot, \cdot]$ which is linear in the first and the third variables and conjugate linear in the second. That is, we let $X_n$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be a term, and for any term $t_1, t_2, t_3$, we let $[t_1, t_2, t_3]$ be a term. Then let $F$ be the linear space of formal linear combinations of terms, equipped with the triple product:
$$[\sum_i c^{(1)}_it^{(1)}_i, \sum_j c^{(2)}_jt^{(2)}_j, \sum_k c^{(3)}_kt^{(3)}_k] = \sum_{i,j,k} c^{(1)}_i\overline{c^{(2)}_j}c^{(3)}_k [t^{(1)}_i, t^{(2)}_j, t^{(3)}_k]$$
(We may also impose additional axioms on terms if they are satisfied by all TROs, such as $[t_1, t_2, [t_3, t_4, t_5]] = [t_1, [t_4, t_3, t_2], t_5] = [[t_1, t_2, t_3], t_4, t_5]$. But this isn't necessary.) Then consider the "universal representation" of $F$ in separable TROs where all generators are contractions, i.e., let $\pi$ be the direct sum of all (isomorphism class representatives, in order to avoid set-theoretic complications) of representations into separable TROs, $\pi = \oplus_{i \in I} \pi_i$, where $\|\pi_i(X_n)\| \leq 1$ for all $n$. Note that this is well-defined since any for any term $t$, $\|\pi_i(t)\| \leq 1$ for all $i$, so $\|\pi_i(\sum_j c_jt_j)\| \leq \sum_j |c_j|$ for all $i$. Now, let $A = \overline{\pi(F)}$, or equivalently let $A$ be the completion of $F$ under the seminorm $\|\pi(\cdot)\| = \sup_i \|\pi_i(\cdot)\|$.
The TRO $A$ constructed in these two different ways are easily seen to be naturally isomorphic. It is clearly separable, and, for any separable TRO $T$, we may choose countably many contractions $\{x_n\}_n$ generating $T$, then there is a TRO morphism $\phi: A \to T$ with $\phi(X_n) = x_n$. The only thing we need to observe here is that the range of $\phi$ is $T$. Clearly, the range of $\phi$ is dense. That it is closed follows from, say, Proposition 2.1(iii) in this paper.
